# Dropping out the background

Tags: iphoto

I'm using iPhoto to download images of clothing on a mannequin against a white backdrop.  I take the images and put them in preview, go to "tools", "adjust color" and use the magic wand or lasso to drop out the background.  Then I dump that image back into iPhoto to clean it up.  It's so time consuming and tedious, is there an easier way to do this with what I've got?  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you're using _iPhoto_? It was discontinued in 2015. You could only have it if you have a Mac from before OS X Yosemite (10.10.3).

Comment: @scottbb It seems fairly plausible that someone might be using software from two years ago. Not everyone lives on Internet Time. :)

Comment: @mattdm True, and fair criticism. =)  I suppose my incredulity comes from my experience as a Mac user: once Apple both discontinues a piece of software _and_ replaces it with something "newer! better!", they are aggressive about getting you off the old and onto the new. It's an impressive achievement today to not be on Photos (rather than iPhoto).

Comment: Sorry I mean "photos"

Answer (score 1):

> It's so time consuming and tedious, is there an easier way to do this with what I've got?

Removing the background is a very common task, and so there are lots of tools out there to improve the process. If all you have available are iPhoto (or it's successor, Photos) and Preview, then I don't think there are better ways than what you're currently doing. However, there's no reason that you shouldn't add more tools to your arsenal.

One tool that could help, and which is free, is [ImageMagik](https://www.imagemagick.org). ImageMagick is free and available for all major platforms. The down side is that it's a command-line tool, so you'll need some degree of comfort with that. They have some [instructions for chroma key masking](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/photos/#chroma_key), which is basically what you're trying to do. If you're doing this a lot, you might want to invest in a green or blue screen to shoot against -- the idea is to use a color that's unlikely to appear in the subject, so that the software can easily identify pixels that are part of the background. But as long as your subject doesn't include white, white is fine too.

Tools and techniques for background masking are available for image editing programs like Photoshop and GIMP. Photoshop isn't free, of course, but GIMP is, so that may be another tool to add to your setup. The editing tools in iPhoto and Photos are pretty basic; if you're doing much editing beyond adjusting values for the entire image, you should really look into using some sort of more dedicated photo editing software. iPhoto is really more a photo storage and management tool than an editor.